# Gradle zip how to add filter in place for XML manipulation

Tags: xml, gradle, filter

Gradle zip: how to filter an XML file by adding a new node, for example,

```
task mytask(type: Zip) {

    from ("foo/bar") {

        include "config.xml"
        filter {
             def root = new XmlParser().parser(configXml_inputStream)
             root.hello.world.append(aNode)
             groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root, configXml_outputStream)
        }
    }

}
```

The filter closure parameter is a line, not a File. How to write a custom filter to manipulate an XML file

```
filter(myFilterType)
```

Could not find examples/docs on creating custom Filter.

Answer (score 0):

The filter works on lines, not xml nodes. The following example illustrates a substitution using lines but **note** that this is a *strange* approach for xml, and won't work in the general case.

Given this `foo/bar/config.xml`:

```
<root>
    <hello>
        <world>
        </world>
    </hello>
</root>
```

and **assuming** that there is only one `<world>` element to be augmented, then consider this `build.gradle`:

```
task mytask(type: Zip) {
    archiveName "config.zip"

    from ("foo/bar") {
        include "config.xml"

        filter { line ->
            def result = line

            if (line.trim() == '<world>') {
                def buffer = new StringBuilder()
                buffer.append(line + "\n")
                buffer.append('<aNode type="example">' + "\n")
                buffer.append('</aNode>')
                result = buffer.toString()
            }

            result
        }
    }
}
```

then `config.xml` in `config.zip` is:

```
<root>
    <hello>
        <world>
<aNode type="example">
</aNode>
        </world>
    </hello>
</root>
```